# Notificação via email com springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estou tentando criar uma notificação via email quando um usuário preenche um form, porem não estou tento muita sorte:

> Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

```
@PostMapping("submit")
public ModelAndView submit(@Valid Faq faq, @RequestParam("myFile") MultipartFile myFile, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirectAttr, Locale locale, @AuthenticationPrincipal UserImpl activeUser) throws IOException {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("/index");
    } else {
        faqService.save(faq, myFile);
        faqService.sendMessage(faq, activeUser.getUser());
        redirectAttr.addFlashAttribute("message", messages.get("field.saved"));
    }
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/faq/question");
}
```

método na controller

```
public void sendMessage(Faq faq, User user) {
    SimpleMailMessage mail = new SimpleMailMessage();

    if (faq != null || user != null) {
        if(user.getEmail() != null || user.getName() != null || faq.getQuestion() != null || faq.getAnswer() != null) {
            if(user.getEmail().contains("@") ){
                mail.setTo("petnationapp@gmail.com");
                mail.setFrom("petnationapp@gmail.com");
                mail.setSubject("Nova pergunta");
                mail.setText(
                        "Prezado(a) Administrador " + ", \n\n" + "esta pergunta foi "
                                + faq.getQuestion() + "' foi cadastrado no sistema!\n");
                javaMailSender.send(mail);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Service

Comment: Parece ser relacionado com isso: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17799656/6370247